# How to print M character with heart symbols in C language?

Tags: c++, c

I am new to programming. I want to print SUM with hearts, I got SU but I am unable to print M. Could you please help me with code ?
here is my SU code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    char i=3;
    int j,k;

    for(j=0; j<=8; j++)     //s
        printf("%c",i);

    printf("\n%c\n%c\n",i,i);

    for(j=0; j<=8; j++)
        printf("%c",i);

    printf("\n");

    for(j=0;j<=1; j++)
    {    
        for(k=0; k<=7; k++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        printf("%c\n",i);
    }

    for(j=0; j<=8; j++)
        printf("%c",i);

    printf("\n\n");

    for(j=0; j<=7; j++)
    {      //u
        printf("%c",i);

        for(k=0; k<=1; k++)
            printf("   ");

        printf("%c\n",i);}

        for(j=0; j<=6; j++)
            printf("%c",i);

        printf("\n\n");
    }
```

Comment: Can you format your code so it's more readable.  Ay yai yai!  Can't you just do `printf("SUM\n");`?

Comment: Sorry I can't format more that, as i said that am new to programming i dont know how to format it in correct way.
no i need M with heart symbols, you can see my code output so that you can easily understand what I am asking.

Comment: In addition to formatting the code, use `{}` after every loop, if, etc. Will save you a ton of bug hunting...

Comment: I formatted the code, but it doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @venkataramanareddy Can you manually tell us what the output should be?

Comment: `main` must return an `int`.

Comment: The program prints big letters in a 9x8 grid with char '\03'.

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey yeah sure... I just want to print SUM characters with heart symbols.

Comment: ASCII code `'\03'` is not printable...

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey please run the given code once so that you can understand what exactly I want.

Comment: @venkataramanareddy  I will

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey Thank you :) please run it in codeblocks if you have!

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey, it appears to be running in a Windows command window with code page 437, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437

Comment: @MarkRansom Thanks.  I feel like a doofus. lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following code to the bottom.  `\x03` is hexadecimal code for the heart character on a US Windows console, which I assume you are using:

```
printf("\x03       \x03\n");
printf("\x03\x03     \x03\x03\n");
printf("\x03 \x03   \x03 \x03\n");
printf("\x03  \x03 \x03  \x03\n");
printf("\x03   \x03   \x03\n");
printf("\x03       \x03\n");
printf("\x03       \x03\n");
```

Output of the whole program:

```
♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
♥
♥
♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
        ♥
        ♥
♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥

♥      ♥
♥      ♥
♥      ♥
♥      ♥
♥      ♥
♥      ♥
♥      ♥
♥      ♥
♥♥♥♥♥♥♥

♥       ♥
♥♥     ♥♥
♥ ♥   ♥ ♥
♥  ♥ ♥  ♥
♥   ♥   ♥
♥       ♥
♥       ♥
```

Answer (score 3):

I would set it up like this

```
char letter_s[7] = {
    0b11111111,
    0b10000000,
    0b10000000,
    0b11111111,
    0b00000001,
    0b00000001,
    0b11111111 };

char letter_m[7] = {
    0b10000010,
    0b11000110,
    0b10101010,
    0b10010010,
    0b10000010,
    0b10000010,
    0b10000010 };
```

and then write code to print '\03' for every 1 bit in a character array.