# How to use binary array control the corresponding location to use "printf" to print some patterms?

Tags: c, printf

I find this question:
[How to print M character with heart symbols in C language?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20179550/how-to-print-m-character-with-heart-symbols-in-c-language)
and one answer is use binary array to set position that need to print.

```
char letter_s[7] = {
    0b11111111,
    0b10000000,
    0b10000000,
    0b11111111,
    0b00000001,
    0b00000001,
    0b11111111 };

char letter_m[7] = {
    0b10000010,
    0b11000110,
    0b10101010,
    0b10010010,
    0b10000010,
    0b10000010,
    0b10000010 };
//and then write code to print '\03' for every 1 bit in a character array.
```

print pattern like this:

```
♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
♥
♥
♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
        ♥
        ♥
♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥♥
```

I try to implement this, use

```
char letter_s[1] = {0b11111111};
printf("%d", letter_s[0][0]);
```

but I can't reach the bit level. so I was wondering how to use 1 and 0 to control wheteher input or not input.
I'm new to C language, I don’t know which part of the C language knowledge system can find the answer，is bit fiddling? I use book of C Premier Plus, I read this chapter but still don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access individual bits of a char variable, you need to use bitwise operators.

In your example, what you need to use is the bitwise AND operator, denoted by **&**, and optionally the left shift operator, denoted by **<<**.

Here is an example that will print out each bit of a char variable, from the least significant bit to the most significant bit:

```
char c = 0b10101010;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) {
    int bit = (c & (1 << i)) != 0;
    printf("Bit %d: %d\n", i, bit);
}
```

Will print out:

```
Bit 0: 0
Bit 1: 1
Bit 2: 0
Bit 3: 1
Bit 4: 0
Bit 5: 1
Bit 6: 0
Bit 7: 1
```